# SELECT COUNT from two tables is not working

Tags: sql, count, left-join

I have two tables - first table is "projects":

| p_id | p_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 |
| 2 | test2 |
| 3 | test2 |
| 4 | test3 |

p_name is not unique

The second table is "employee":

| e_id | jan | feb | mar | apr | may |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

I'd like to count how many p_name in employee depending on name

What I do:

```
select 
    p.id, p.name, 
    count(e1.jan) as e1, 
    count(e2.feb) as e2, 
    count(e3.mar) as e3  
from 
    projects p 
left join 
    employee e1 on (e1.jan = p.id) 
left join 
    employee e2 on (e2.feb = p.id) 
left join 
    employee e3 on (e3.mar = p.id) 
where 
    p.name = 'test2' 
group by 
    p.name;
```

But it doesn't work. It doesn't return the expected numbers.

Comment: How would you propose this would scale to a full year or several years? I would suggest your Employee table to be structured wth Year Month and ProjectId column. This then becomes very easy!

Comment: there's a year table but this is working structure unfortunately. So, I'm looking for solution in this particular case

Comment: It's clear why it doesn't work. Take just the project 3, and the months Feb and March. You start with one row, the project. Then you join on the Feb employees for project 3, of which there are two, so now you have two rows.  Then you do the same for march, and again there are two rows, but because you had two rows after Feb was joined you now have 2*2 rows, which is four rows.  You need to aggregate Before you join, not after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely agree with the comment of @sTTu - the chosen design is not scalable and will run into problems as soon as a "new year" starts.

Purely out of curiousity I tried to come up with a solution nonetheless which would be the following:

(SQL-Server - but should also work in MySql)

```
SELECT name, SUM(jan) Jan, SUM(feb) feb, SUM(mar) mar FROM (
  SELECT id, name, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM employee WHERE jan=id) jan,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM employee WHERE feb=id) feb,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM employee WHERE mar=id) mar
  from projects ) tbl
group by name;
```

Here is a working snippet: https://rextester.com/TBWZA82894

Result:

| name | Jan | feb | mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| test2 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| test3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Or, in an even simpler way you can do it like this:

```
SELECT name,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN jan=id THEN 1 END) jan,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN feb=id THEN 1 END) feb,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN mar=id THEN 1 END) mar
FROM employee 
INNER JOIN projects ON id>0
GROUP BY name
```

see the demo here: https://rextester.com/DEUUE59264

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well. I agree, the design is not scalable. Most likely I will rewrite it later

Answer (score 2):

It would be clearer to understand your goal if you could supply the example dataset you expect to see.

However you might try something like the following using an apply() for each month

```
select p.id,p.[name], e1.qty, e2.qty, e3.qty, e4.qty, e5.qty
from 
projects p 
outer apply ( select count(*) qty from employee e where e.jan = p.id )e1
outer apply ( select count(*) qty from employee e where e.feb = p.id )e2
outer apply ( select count(*) qty from employee e where e.mar = p.id )e3
outer apply ( select count(*) qty from employee e where e.apr = p.id )e4
outer apply ( select count(*) qty from employee e where e.may = p.id )e5
where p.name = 'test2'
```

Comment: does mysql supports outer apply?

Comment: The question is not tagged as mysql? I believe mysql has an alternative syntax known as a lateral join; outer apply in this case is a less verbose way of achieving left-joining to a derived table, as in: left join (select jan, count(*) qty from employee group by jan) e1 on e1.jan = p.id etc...

Comment: thanks, it almost ok, but due to non-unique name it still doesn't return correct value. In any case I can sum up the values later because now I can return the correct COUNT for each NAME. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(jan) from employee where jan in (
select p_id from projects where p_name = 'test1')
```

you can do it like this and get the output for each column alone

Comment: thanks, but how to get it with one the response from several columns?

Answer (score 0):

It's clear why it doesn't work. Take just the project 3, and the months Feb and March. You start with one row, the project. Then you join on the Feb employees for project 3, of which there are two, so now you have two rows.  Then you do the same for march, and again there are two rows, but because you had two rows after Feb was joined you now have 2*2 rows, which is four rows.  You need to aggregate Before you join, not after.

I'd use the outer apply method. But an easier to understand option might be to aggregate then join.

```
select 
    p.id, p.name, 
    e1.jan as e1, 
    e2.feb as e2, 
    e3.mar as e3  
from 
    projects p 
left join 
    (SELECT jan AS pid, COUNT(*) AS jan FROM employee) e1 on (e1.pid = p.id) 
left join 
    (SELECT feb AS pid, COUNT(*) AS feb FROM employee) e2 on (e2.pid = p.id)
left join 
    (SELECT mar AS pid, COUNT(*) AS mar FROM employee) e3 on (e3.pid = p.id)
left join 
    (SELECT apr AS pid, COUNT(*) AS apr FROM employee) e4 on (e4.pid = p.id)
where 
    p.name = 'test2'
```

Comment: this doesn't work unfortunately. returns NULL in most of cases